# Locations Connections of Facebook Graph Api User object not responding properly in ios-sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to retrieve Posts, statuses, and photos in which a user has been tagged at a location, using the locations in user connections. The problem is that while using the proper permissions and getting the demanded results in Graph Api Explorer the same does not happen in  my app. The response only returns with the user id missing the location key. The code i use is the following:

For permissions:

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"friends_status",@"friends_photos",nil];

if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                message:error.localizedDescription
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        } else if (session.isOpen) {
            [self pickFriendsButtonClick:sender];
        }
    }];
    return;
}
```

To retrieve data:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [selectedFbFriends count]; i++) {
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/friends/%@?fields=locations",selectedFbFriends[i]];

    FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:path];
    [friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id<FBGraphObject> result, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"%@",result[@"data"]);
}
```

The result is not the same as using the same path in Graph Api Explorer. I only get the user id. My head is gonna burst because i can not find what is wrong and the permission seem to be proper ones. Any help out there would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: double check that you use the same friend id both in graph api explorer and in your app. for me works fine. I get only the user id for some friends that do not have any locations in their profile

Comment: unfortunately i use the same id. only in app the response misses the location key... it's crazier now that you tell me that for you it works... thanks though

Comment: please print down the value of the 'path' variable

Comment: @Vame `2013-07-08 19:23:27.542 FriendSample[594:c07] me/friends/204500396?fields=locations`

Comment: @Vame copy pasting the same to graph api explorer i get the proper results

Comment: @Vame what i notice is that if i use checkins instead of locations fields i get results with those permission in my app. the problem seems to be with the locations field. And unfortunately i need locations instead of just checkins...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like that function doesn't consider the parameters as a part of the path. You can use this:

```
- (FBRequest*)requestWithGraphPath:(NSString *)graphPath
               andParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params
               andDelegate:(id <FBRequestDelegate>)delegate;
```

source: `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/request/`

where params will be:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:@"locations" forKey:@"fields"];
```

Comment: While with the above function i couldn't understand clearly how to implement it, you gave me a good starting point where to look. I used the below function which seems to be working and getting me the desired results! Thanks alot for your time.     `NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dict setObject:@"locations" forKey:@"fields"];
        FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:path parameters:dict HTTPMethod:@"GET"];`